# Can't access data from redux toolkit with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently learning typescript by creating a very simple todo app using React, Redux-toolkit and Typescript. When i try to access data from the store with useSelector, i get an object containing the value that i want (in this case an array of Todo).

```
//TodoList.tsx
const todos = useSelector(selectTodos)
```

Console.log of todos :

```
Object { todos: (1) […] }
```

```
//TodoSlice.tsx
export const selectTodos = (state: RootState): Todo[] => state.todos
```

The problem is that i cannot access the array because according to the TS compiler, this value does not exist (but according to the console it is there !)

If you want more information, check the full code [here](https://github.com/Kyustern/UCTDA/tree/master/src)

Cheers, and thanks in advance !
(also sorry for the possible typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you are defining as `RootState` is *not* the root state, but just your slice state type.

You can get your actual `RootState` via

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        todos: todosReducer
    }
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Then you'll actually notice that your todos are in `state.todos.todos`, not in `state.todos`.